# Can I reorder the adjectives this way?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the original headline is:

> Villagers walking near a newly built state-owned coal fired power plant in Liuzhi County, China, in 2017. China is the world’s biggest source of greenhouse gases.

If was writing this headline it would be like:

> Villagers walking near a newly STATE-OWNED BUILT COAL FIRE POWER PLANT in Liuzhi County, China, in 2017. China is the world’s biggest source of greenhouse gases.

basing on the fact the power plant in order to belong to the state it needs to be built first. Make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Not in this case, because "newly built" functions as a single element in the list of adjectives.

*A state-owned built coal fired power plant* would be possible, but reads very oddly, because it's hard to see what kind of plant would not be "built".

Answer (score 0):

No, your word order does not make sense.

"Newly *past-participle*" means that the action is recent.  In this case, the building of the power plant is recent, but your version says that the state ownership is recent.

Also, then *built* stands alone by itself, and we lose the meaning of the original sentence that the power power has been built recently.

Lastly, no, the power plant does not have to be built before it could belong to the state.  If the state owned the land and ordered the construction of the power plant, then it has always belonged to the state.